# Android emulator icons missing

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm using a standard Android Studio emulator. The problem is icons missing and other problems, like home screen text issues.

Text issues are not a problem for now, but icons are trouble. I can't turn WiFi on an emulator. Here is how it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/REcCE.png

Is there is something to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem then fixed it by changing the renderer like this:

[image: Valid XHTML].

Just choose the renderer that works for you.